# missing several fields in a bibliographic entry

Tags: bibtex, natbib, hyphenation

Clarification: I'm writing a thesis.

Edit: It seems that my TeXworks doesn't compile -- to a en-dash, any idea why? I just use – for now with XeTeX.

I compile with XeLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTex and use `natbib` with `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`

Example:

```
@article{brown1960,
  title={The Pronouns of Power and Solidarity},
  author={Brown, Roger and Gilman, Albert},
  journal={Style in Language},
  volume={2},
  editor={Sebeok, Thomas A.},
  pages={253--76},
  publisher={MIT Press},
  address={Cambridge},
  year={1960}
}
```

produces

[image]

1. Editor, volume, publisher and address is lost.
2. Two dashes -- don't become a hyphen.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

\citet{brown1960}

\bibliography{sources}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You are using `article` for a book: it's not surprising that some fields don't print. On the `--` situation, I suspect that you've got a copy-paste issue and that one or both are not standard hyphens: I'd try deleting the two chars and retyping (only a single hyphen, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you're looking to reference an entry (probably a chapter) in a book. If that's the case, you should

- use the `@incollection` entry type instead of the currently-used `@article` entry type, and
- use the field type `booktitle` instead of `journal` for the field "Style in Language".

With these two modifications in place (and still using the `plainnat` bibliography style), I get the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I checked the optional fields of article and you are right, there is no volume, etc.